# Change ID and NAME from several elements inside DIV JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am using the following script to manage FormSets on Django:

```
function addForm(btn, prefix) {
    var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());

        // Clone a form (without event handlers) from the first form
        var row = $(".item-wrapper:first").clone(false).get(0);
        // Makes a naked copy of them
        $(row).children().find(":input").val('');
        // Inserts into discount and quantity default values
        // Searches for id that contains discount
        $(row).children().find('[id*=discount]').val('0');
        $(row).children().find('[id*=quantity]').val('1.0');
        // Insert it after the last form
        $(row).removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter(".item-wrapper:last").slideDown(300);

        // Remove the bits we don't want in the new row/form
        // e.g. error messages
        $(".action-warning", row).remove();
        $(row).children().removeClass("error");

        // Relabel or rename all the relevant bits (???????)
        $(row).children().children().children().each(function () {
            updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
            $(this).val("");
        });

        // Add an event handler for the delete item/form link
        $(row).find("#delete").click(function () {
            return deleteForm(this, prefix);
        });
        // Update the total form count
        $("#id_" + prefix + "-TOTAL_FORMS").val(formCount + 1);

    return false;
}
```

The problem is that I have four fields inside several Divs that I need to get attributes renamed.

```
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
        <div class="item-child-name">
            {{ form.name.label_tag }}
            <div class="ui-widget">{{ form.name }}</div>
        </div>

    <div class="item-child-dis">
        {{ form.discount.label_tag }}
        {{ form.discount }}
    </div>

<!-- HERE MORE OTHER 4 FORMS -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to make sure all labels and inputs attributes from these forms get renamed, however the method (I added ????? in the line) used is a bit static and goes only through a few elements. I could see that if I increase the children() function it advances to another element, renaming it. 
What is the better approach on this?

Here is the original js file: https://github.com/rotaris/Dynamic-Form-Todo-Add-in-Django/blob/master/templates/todo/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I was doing because the answer was in my face the whole time:

```
$(row).find('*').each(function () {
    updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
});
```

Now I can rename all labels and input children of the specified div whose name matches my regular expression.